# Access Database Synchronizer with network location

Tags: ms-access, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Using the [Access Database Synchronizer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B967347A-5DD0-445C-8A9F-AEA3DB9EC4BC&displaylang=en) has anyone been able to synchronize with an mdb stored in a network location?

It doesn't even work if i map a network drive to my local c: i.e. c:\test.mdb works but z:\test.mdb doesn't.

I simply get a System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException "Failure to open SQL Server with given connect string."

Comment: Are you actually using SQL Server CE? That is, the compact edition that runs on Windows Mobile (formerly Windows CE)?

Comment: Aye, this doesn't make a great deal of sense. Why are you using SqlCe while talking about mapping something to your "C:\" drive. A mobile device doesn't have a C:\ in most cases.

Comment: Using the Access Database Synchronizer from MS allows you sync a SQLCE database with an Access database on your local machine. It allows you to specify the location of the mdb, hence c:\. Problem is I can't get it to sync to a "network" drive, even if I map z:\ to c:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question now. Seems as though no-one has an answer (or even heard of it).

Access Database Synchronizer won't work when using a network drive, most likely a bug in the product.